# The Method is undefined for the type object Eclipse error

Tags: java, android, apache

I'm new to android programming and am following this tutorial http://javapapers.com/android/android-twitter-feed-reader/ to make a live twitter feed however I have errors on `getStatusCode()` and `getReasonPhrase()`. Any help on how to fix this would be appreciated.

My code is as follows

```
package com.javapapers.java.io;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class HttpUtil {

    public String getHttpResponse(HttpRequestBase request) {
        String result = null;
        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String reason = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                String line = null;
                while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                sb.append(reason);
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        } catch (ClientProtocolException ex1) {
        } catch (IOException ex2) {
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare them? That is its issue

Comment: I have the exact same code as the tutorial http://javapapers.com/android/android-twitter-feed-reader/

Comment: Never said you didn't. But those are not declared in the code you provided, hence the error

Comment: @Spencer4134 when I click on the it the quick fix says "Add cast to method receiver"

Comment: What is the statusCode and the reason that you are getting?